# How to download Amazon reports by using the Amazon MWS API

Tags: c#, amazon-mws

I am using the Amazon Reports API Client Library - C# - Version 2009-01-01 from this link: [Amazon Reports Client C#](https://developer.amazonservices.in/doc/bde/reports/v20090101/cSharp.html/260-5585436-2368834).

The issue is that even following the samples from that library, the GetReport() method from the MarketplaceWebServiceClient.cs class will not return the real Report in the GetReportResponse() response.

Something seems to be happening there to where the GetReportResponse returns NULL instead of with any data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a couple of hour of Googling I think I found the answer to this question. 
The Amazon library samples will never get the correct results if you follow them.

So, I've got the correct answer from this site: [download-amazon-reports-using-mws-api](https://dzone.com/articles/download-amazon-reports-using-mws-api)

Basically, the most important lines are these ones:

```cs
var request = new GetReportRequest();

//... (more details in a few)

var path = request.ReportId + "_" + Guid.NewGuid();
var thePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + string.Format("{0}.txt", path);

request.Report = File.Open(thePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);  <-- this line makes the trick!
```

You need to open a file and pass the reference when requesting the report.
The returned report file will be located at the `thePath`.

Here is a test method I created you can use to retrieve your reports. Update your MWS API credentials accordingly. You will also need to download the Amazon Reports API Library C# from the link above.

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetReport()
        {
            // Developer AWS access key
            var accessKey = "[YOUR-ACCESS-KEY]";

            // Developer AWS secret key
            var secretKey = "[YOUR-SECRET-KEY]";

            // The client application name
            var appName = "MWS Reports API SAMPLE";

            // The client application version
            var appVersion = "1.0";

            // The endpoint for region service and version (see developer guide)
            // ex: https://mws.amazonservices.com
            var serviceURL = "https://mws.amazonservices.com";

            var config = new MarketplaceWebServiceConfig();
            config.ServiceURL = serviceURL;

            var client = new MarketplaceWebServiceClient(accessKey, secretKey, appName, appVersion, config);

            var request = new GetReportRequest();
            var sellerId = "[YOUR-SELLER-ID]";
            request.Merchant = sellerId;
            var mwsAuthToken = "[YOUR-MWS-AUTH-TOKEN]";
            request.MWSAuthToken = mwsAuthToken;
            request.ReportId = "[YOUR-REPORT-ID]";

            var path = request.ReportId + "_" + Guid.NewGuid();
            var thePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + string.Format("{0}.txt", path);

            request.Report = File.Open(thePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            //request.ReportTypeList = new TypeList { Type = new List<string> { "_GET_V2_SETTLEMENT_REPORT_DATA_XML_" } };

            try
            {
                GetReportResponse response = null;
                response = client.GetReport(request);
                Console.WriteLine("Response:");
                var rhmd = response.ResponseHeaderMetadata;
                // We recommend logging the request id and timestamp of every call.
                Console.WriteLine("RequestId: " + rhmd.RequestId);
                Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: " + rhmd.Timestamp);
                var responseXml = response.ToXML();
                Console.WriteLine(responseXml);
                request.Report.Close();
            }
            catch (MarketplaceWebServiceException ex)
            {
                // Exception properties are important for diagnostics.
                ResponseHeaderMetadata rhmd = ex.ResponseHeaderMetadata;
                Console.WriteLine("Service Exception:");
                if (rhmd != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("RequestId: " + rhmd.RequestId);
                    Console.WriteLine("Timestamp: " + rhmd.Timestamp);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("StatusCode: " + ex.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("ErrorCode: " + ex.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine("ErrorType: " + ex.ErrorType);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```